# Trouble with SD card in Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, external-sd, prestigio-multipad

I've recently been given a **Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B** (Android 4.0) which I thought would be nice for my daughter to watch videos on. I took an 8GB micro SDHC card from my Windows 7 laptop (NTFS format) and put it into the SD card slot but it wasn't detected.

After a bit of a read I tried formatting it as FAT32/exFat and inserting it but for both formats when going to the system settings screen > storage screen there is no card listed and no option to do anything.

So I have two questions:

- How can I be sure the SD card is inserted correctly? It seems like it wants to slip out
- How can I get an SD card working with this device

I don't want to go out and get a new SD card until I'm sure it works correctly as otherwise it would be a waste of money.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the fact that it is a SDHC card. SDHC cards are rather new, and are not supported yet in most devices. So maybe you could try to find a normal SDSC card (from digital camera, friends, family..) to test if it works with that type.

The reason why SDHC cards are not yet supported in some devices is because it uses another type of Card-Specific Data (CSD) register. This results in some compatibility issues with some (older) devices. But if you want to know more about this, I recommond to use Google.

I would think though that a new device like yours (because it has Android 4.0) would support this already.. I haven't heard of the brand before, so I don't really know the quality of their devices.

**EDIT**: The device should support SDHC cards up to 32GB according to the [specs](http://www.comx-computers.co.za/PMP3370B-specifications-62658.htm), so that can't be the problem. I suggest contacting the support then, maybe they can tell you what is wrong and what you can try..

Comment: I don't have a link to the spec page handy but it is meant to support SDHC

Comment: Indeed, you are correct: http://www.comx-computers.co.za/PMP3370B-specifications-62658.htm. Then I cannot really help you I'm afraid. Maybe just contact their support